# Full Disk LUKS in Debian, Unable to boot after rename partition name in crypttab

Tags: linux, boot, debian, lvm, luks

Here is the lsblk info:

```
sdf1                   vfat    efi
sdf2                   ext2    boot
sdf3 crypto_LU
 --- sdf3_crypto  LVM2
   --- name--vg--root  EXT4   /
   --- name--vg--swap  swap   [SWAP]
```

Problem: I renamed the partition /etc/crypttab (sdf3_crypto was called sdg3_crypto before)

Then, `update-initramfs -u` and restart.

And the server won't boot, error info somehow looks like

> Unable to find LVM volumn: name--vg--root

I guess the boot loader can't find the correct hard drive to decrypt, then, of course, no lvm found.

Then, how can I fix this?  I tried to mount at Debian live CD and success.

But I can't run `update-initramfs -u` with the live CD.

More info (might be helpful):

It's Debian 8 x64 with dell PERC hardware RAID 1 SSDs, UEFI mode

Comment: The UUID is used in crypttab

Comment: You can run `update-initramfs` from a live CD if you mount your hard-drive-installed system somewhere and chroot into it.

Comment: Yes, you are right, that's exactly what i did later. Finally, I reinstall the whole system in BIOS mode instead of UEFI, There were many wired things happened with UEFI. such as, `Unable to find LVM volumn` on boot after a fresh install(with multiple HDDs), unable to show the passphase prompt for the second LUKS,